# Does Chase's QuickDeposit feature work on the iPod Touch 4G?

Tags: ipod-touch, camera

Now that the new iPod Touch has a camera, I'm thinking of buying it.
However, since Apple crippled its resolution (960 x 720), I'm not so sure.

Does Chase Mobile's QuickDeposit feature work with the lower camera resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like they just updated to version 2.8.1202, release notes say "Quick Deposit for iPod touch - Now you can use your camera-enabled iPod touch to make a deposit."